# How to get user data with python social auth..?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I have created a small project using python social auth for logging with facebook.I have referred python social auth example at [link](http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2014/04/tutorial-adding-facebooktwittergoogle-authentication-to-a-django-application/).I can able to get the user name with `request.name`.But how can i get the other data like `first_name`,`last_name`,`email`.Any help would be appriciated

example code in views is:

```
def home(request):
   context = RequestContext(request,
                       {'request': request,
                        'user': request.user})
   return render_to_response('home.html',
                         context_instance=context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way: `request.user` has a helper method called `is_authenticated`, which you can use like this:

```
ctx = {
       'user' : request.user
      }

if request.user.is_authenticated():
    ctx.update({
         'first_name': request.user.first_name,
         'last_name': request.user.last_name,
         'email' : request.user.email
    })
```

Now, the extra attributes are present  *only* if the user is authenticated
This is, assuming you are using the `auth` model of django. If not, please change the model field names accordingly.

On a side note, you should not be passing the entire request object in the context. You should be extracting only the relevant info and sending it in the context.

Now, you can access *all* these values from the template anyways. Example:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    {{request.user.username}}
    {{request.user.email}}
    {# etc.. #}
{% endif %}
```

No need to send anything in the context explicitly. The `request` object already has everything

Comment: Thank you and what are the list of values we are getting if user is authenticated...?

Comment: You have to add `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']` in `settings.py` in order to obtain the email from Facebook.

Comment: If you mean _not_ authenticated, this context actually does not make any sense,as it would have `user`. On second thought, you can get all these values from the template itself. Let me edit the answer